# CSS Grid - keep all children on one row and equally spaced

Tags: css, css-grid

Using CSS Grid, how can I keep all of the children in one row when you don't know how many children there will be?

I need all children to have equal `width`, so if there are 2 children they will each have 50% width and if there are 3 children they each get 33.33% width etc.

```
.container {
   display: grid;
}

<div class='container'>
   <div>Child 1</div>
   <div>Child 2</div>
   <div>Child 3</div>
   // There maybe 4 or 5 children we don't know
</div>
```

Comment: Its probably better to use flexbox for variable amounts of children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily CSS grid by using `repeat`, `auto-fit`, and `minmax`.

Essentially what we are doing here is setting the child elements to take up the full width of whatever their "grid container" is, and then we are setting the grid to be `auto-fit` and saying that each child will be a minimum of `50px` or a maximum of `1fr`.

Another good approach would be to just use `grid-auto-columns` and `grid-auto-flow`. Kind of depends on your specific use case for which is the better approach, but be sure to checkout [Temani Afif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385561/4826740) for the other solution.

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Example 1:

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

Example 2:

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

Example 3:

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tomato is the new red <3

Answer (score 5):

Use a column flow and keep all the size `1fr`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Example 1:

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

Example 2:

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

Example 3:

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: aww this is good too